# Easy label lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to make lots of map label lines (linking points with their corresponding labels, placed nearby..) in the following style in Illustrator:

[image]

It's quite labour intensive to arrange separate lines and ellipses, and yet more work to adjust them later if necessary.  Does anyone know an Illustrator plugin or fix to make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a line and in the Stroke panel give it arrowheads for both ends, selecting the closed bullet arrowhead.
2. Drag this line over to the Graphic Styles panel - this saves the appearance as a Graphic Style that can be applied to other objects.
3. Draw out all your label lines on your map.
4. Select all these label lines and then select your saved style from the Graphics Style panel. All your label lines will now get the bulleted arrowhead appearance.

Comment: Nice solution thanks.  I group two such lines and replicate them - these can be re-scaled easily.